# Is it possible to write data on iBeacon

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, core-bluetooth

I am going to use iBeacon in my app. Is it possible to write values on it, when the app is opened. If yes how do I achieve this. By using coreBluetooth I can do this.

```
NSData *bytes = [@"0xDE" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[peripheral writeValue:bytes forCharacteristic:characteristic
        type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

Comment: If you will read iBeacons in detail, you will came to know that all iBeacons have some static ids, with which a particular beacon is identified. You can use that ids to identify and store data for that beacon. For more ease follow this sdk: http://developer.estimote.com/ibeacon/tutorial/part-1-setting-up/

Comment: If the iBeacon allows a "classic BLE" mode, and that it has writable characteristic, yes you can.

Answer (score 5):

An iBeacon just advertises 3 values; a UUID, a "major" value and a "minor" value.

Beacons typically have some BLE service and characteristics that are used for configuring these and other parameters (such as advertising rate and transmit power) but this is outside of the iBeacon specification; each vendor will have their own service and characteristics.

Comment: This is correct.  To add to this, while it is common for beacon manufacturers to have a custom bluetooth GATT service to write these configuration values to the beacon, not all beacons have this.   Some beacons have hard-coded values that are not configurable and some are configurable using other mechanisms than bluetooth connections.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know the different between iBeacon(bluetooth beacons) and ordinary Bluetooth device. (You can google it)

The CoreBluetooth function you are calling is for `altering values on connected bluetooth peripheral`, the keywords are `connected bluetooth peripheral` which iBeacon is not.

Bluetooth peripherals include GATT server, which allows bluetooth centrals to connect and access its services and characteristics.

While iBeacon just advertises, UUID, major, minor, RSSI. No GATT server, no services or characteristics.

To conclude, there is NO SIMPLE WAY (using bluetooth only) to alter the value ('UUID', 'major', 'minor') on a ORDINARY BEACON.

But some beacon manufacturers do provide some similar solutions, they add extra hardware to beacons (network hard). And provide web portal for beacon owner the control the beacon remotely.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an app which can modify the iBeacon data of Bluetooth device recently.

> *There is no standard method in Bluetooth Specification for you to write iBeacon data.*

**It means that you must use the custom command as you and Bluetooth firmware developer both agree to do this,whatever kind of data communication,different vendor has different methods,both of app developer and Bluetooth firmware developer agree, this is enough!**